# Kochen-Specker theorem and measurement map in the formalism of QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, measurement-problem, quantum-measurements

There is (or rather was) a famous debate between Born and Einstein about interpretational issues of Quantum Mechanics.
In this debate Einstein was advocating the so called *theory of hidden variables*. There are various no-go
theorems ruling out the possibility of the existence of such hidden variables. One possible formulation of
existence of hidden variables is as follows: there should exist a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and
two maps $F: \mathcal{O} \to L^{\infty}(\Omega), A \mapsto F_A$ (where $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is the space of all bounded
measurable functions on $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{O}$ is the space of all self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$)
and $\rho: \mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{M}(\Omega), \psi \mapsto \rho^{\psi} $
(from the space of unit vectors in $\mathcal{H}$ (where $dim(\mathcal{H})>2$) to the space of probability measures on $\Omega$). These maps
should satisfy two conditions:
a) $F_{u(A)}=u \circ F_A$ for every real valued measurable bounded function $u$ and $A \in \mathcal{O}$
b) $\mu^{\psi}_A(\Delta)=\rho^{\psi}(F_A^{-1}(\Delta))$.
One possible formulation of the Kochen-Specker theorem states that such two maps do not exist: in fact Kochen-Specker theorem states that there is no *valuation* from $\mathcal{O}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (where valuation is by definition a scalar valued map which satisfies property a) as above).

Now let me mention another (whether is it really another problem will be the content of my question) problem, namely: there is no honest mapping $\mathcal{O} \times \mathcal{S} \to \mathbb{R}$ within the formalism of QM which would correspond to the outcome of a measurement of an observable in the given state. Suppose that actually *there are hidden variables* and after all QM can be viewed clasically (which is not the case)

> What is then the correct definition of the ,,measurement map'' (involving states and hidden variables)?

So to be clear at this point: I know that *there are no* hidden variables and also there *is no reasonable* measurement map. However what am I aiming at is as follows: I would like to see a natural definition of the measurement map (involving hidden variables) and then prove a theorem:
,,such measurement map exists $\iff$ there exists a valuation on $\mathcal{O}$ (or any equivalent statement of Kochen-Specker theorem)-therefore as Kochen-Specker forbids the existence of valuation thus such a measurement map cannot exist''.

Comment: "_I know that there are no hidden variables [...]_" Isn't Bohmian mechanics an example of a hidden variable theory, albeit a nonlocal and contextual one?